# Grails upload files with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails

i have an angular ui and grails as end points, i posted the files it went ok, but grails seems can't read it.

my angular codes

```
function sendComment(comment, cb, cbError,token) {
        //var promise = $q.defer();


        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('email', comment.email);
        formData.append('PNR', comment.PNR);
        formData.append('content', comment.content);
        formData.append('commentFile',file);


        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: ENV.baseurl +"api/addComment",
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Accept': "application/json",
                'Content-Type': undefined,
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
            },
            data:formData,

        }




        $http(req).success(cb).error(cbError);
    }
```

my chrome log is

[image]

my grails end point

```
def addComment() {
    Comment comment =new Comment()
    JSONObject respond = new JSONObject()
    comment.content = params.content
    comment.PNR = params.PNR
    comment.email = params.email
    def file = request.getFile('commentFile')
    comment.person = Person.findByEmail(params.email);
    print file



    if (comment.save(flush: true)) {
        if (!file) {

            CommentFiles files = new CommentFiles()
            files.files = new File(file)
            files.contentType = uploadedFile.contentType
            files.comment = comment
            files.save(flush: true)

        }
        respond.error = false;
        respond.message = "comment saved";
        response.status = 201;

    } else {
        print comment.errors.allErrors
        respond.error = true;
        respond.message = "Could not save comment";
        response.status = 409;
    }

}
```

the endpoint have a CORS Interceptor in it, but i'm not 100% sure

please help thanks!

Comment: i use grails 3.1.5 and it import import grails.converters.JSON
import org.grails.web.json.JSONObject

Comment: Try without `transformRequest: angular.identity,`

Comment: hi Kleeh it works now, thanks :)

Comment: hi i add for multiple uploads with this request.getFiles("commentFile").each {
            print it.contentType

        }, but it shows Cannot cast object '[object File],[object File]' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'

Answer (score 0):

Try without `transformRequest: angular.identity,`

thanks James Kleeh